# jquery button click not working , using django templates for rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

> I have multiple buttons on the same page with same id so basically
> rendering in a for loop with same id . I set a click event handler in
> jquery but it fires for only the first button.
>
> Can you suggest?

Comment: `I have multiple buttons on the same page with same id ` - you've pointed out your problem right there. Use a class, not an ID.

Comment: cannot use class, class is also same on all the buttons. The event will bubble to every button upon click the way you suggested because they have the same class

Comment: well please share your code using a class that does not work, because you must be doing something wrong. It's hard to be concrete without seeing any code

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating ids are causing your HTML to be invalid. Javascript (and jQuery) assumes that there is a single id, therefore:

```
$("#yourid")
```

will not search for the id further.

You can sidetrack the issue via

```
$("[id=yourid]")
```

which will find all the elements, but that's not advisable, because then your HTML is still invalid. A better approach would be to change your `id` into a `class` and use that as a selector afterwards.

EDIT

In jQuery you can create a click event like this:

```
$("[id=saveFavorite]").click(function() {/*...*/})
```

But even though this will work, I recommend refactoring your code, changing the HTML you have by replacing every `id="saveFavorite"` to `class="saveFavorite"` and do it like this:

```
$(".saveFavorite").click(function() {/*...*/})
```

Comment: But, then how do I bind the click event to every button? I will just share code in  a bit...

Comment: @NikhitaSareen I have edited my answer. The first code is assuming that you still have duplicated ids (change that if possible, even though this will work), the second works with a class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error in console, which probably would be because of same ID for all the buttons. One solution would be to append the index to the button id string so that each button will have unique id(btn1, btn2 etc), or use the class instead of id.

Comment: But then , how do I dynamically bind a click event for every button? Each has a new id now, .each, right?